# CloudFormation: Create resources if they do not exist, but do not delete them

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-sdk, aws-cloudformation

I have the following CloudFormation template. (It is based off default the template created for running C# Web API in AWS Lambda, but that may not be relevant.)

It creates an AWS Lambda function. The template also creates an IAM Role and a DynamoDB table if the names of existing resources are not supplied as arguments.

That part works. If no names are supplied for the role and table, they are created.

**The problem exists when I run the template a second time to perform updates:** at this point, my role and table exist, so I provide the names as arguments. However, when CloudFormation runs the second time, the resources it created the first time (the role and table) are deleted.

**Is there some way to set up the template such that it will create new resources if they don't exist, but not delete them if they are already present?**

I haven't done a lot with CloudFormation, but I did go through the documentation. The closest I found was [setting a stack policy](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/protect-stack-resources.html), but it doesn't seem to be part of the template. It looks like I would have to do this in the management console after the fact.

```
{
  "AWSTemplateFormatVersion" : "2010-09-09",
  "Transform" : "AWS::Serverless-2016-10-31",
  "Description" : "...",

  "Parameters" : {
    "ShouldCreateTable" : {
      "Type" : "String",        
      "AllowedValues" : ["true", "false"],
      "Description" : "If true then the underlying DynamoDB table will be created with the CloudFormation stack."
    },  
    "TableName" : {
        "Type" : "String",
        "Description" : "Name of DynamoDB table to be used for underlying data store. If left blank a new table will be created.",
        "MinLength" : "0"
    },
    "ShouldCreateRole" : {
      "Type" : "String",        
      "AllowedValues" : ["true", "false"],
      "Description" : "If true then the role for the Lambda function will be created with the CloudFormation stack."
    },  
    "RoleARN" : {
        "Type" : "String",
        "Description" : "ARN of the IAM Role used to run the Lambda function. If left blank a new role will be created.",
        "MinLength" : "0"
    }
  },

  "Conditions" : {
    "CreateDynamoTable" : {"Fn::Equals" : [{"Ref" : "ShouldCreateTable"}, "true"]},
    "TableNameGenerated" : {"Fn::Equals" : [{"Ref" : "TableName"}, ""]},
    "CreateRole":{"Fn::Equals" : [{"Ref" : "ShouldCreateRole"}, "true"]},
    "RoleGenerated" : {"Fn::Equals" : [{"Ref" : "RoleARN"}, ""]}
  },

  "Resources" : {

    "Get" : {
      "Type" : "AWS::Serverless::Function",
      "Properties": {
        ...
        "Role": {"Fn::If" : ["CreateRole", {"Fn::GetAtt":["LambdaRole", "Arn"]}, {"Ref":"RoleARN"}]},
        "Environment" : {
          "Variables" : {
            "AppDynamoTable" : { "Fn::If" : ["CreateDynamoTable", {"Ref":"DynamoTable"}, { "Ref" : "TableName" } ] }
          }
        },
        ...
      }
    },

    "LambdaRole":{
        "Type":"AWS::IAM::Role",
        "Condition":"CreateRole",
        "Properties":{
            "ManagedPolicyArns":["arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/AWSLambdaFullAccess"],
            "AssumeRolePolicyDocument": {
               "Version" : "2012-10-17",
               "Statement": [ {
                  "Effect": "Allow",
                  "Principal": {
                     "Service": [ "lambda.amazonaws.com" ]
                  },
                  "Action": [ "sts:AssumeRole" ]
               } ]
            },
            "Policies": [  {
                "PolicyName": "root",
                "PolicyDocument": {
                        "Version": "2012-10-17",
                        "Statement": [
                            {
                                "Effect": "Allow",
                                "Action": [
                                    "dynamodb:Query",
                                    "dynamodb:Scan",
                                    "dynamodb:PutItem",
                                    "dynamodb:GetItem",
                                    "dynamodb:UpdateItem",
                                    "dynamodb:DeleteItem",
                                    "logs:CreateLogGroup",
                                    "logs:CreateLogStream",
                                    "logs:PutLogEvents"
                                ],
                                "Resource": [
                                    "*"
                                ]
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    },

    "DynamoTable" : {
        "Type" : "AWS::DynamoDB::Table",
        "Condition" : "CreateDynamoTable",
        "Properties" : {
            "TableName" : { "Fn::If" : ["TableNameGenerated", {"Ref" : "AWS::NoValue" }, { "Ref" : "TableName" } ] },
            "AttributeDefinitions": [
                { "AttributeName" : "id", "AttributeType" : "S" }
            ],
            "KeySchema" : [
                { "AttributeName" : "id", "KeyType" : "HASH"}
            ],          
            "ProvisionedThroughput" : { "ReadCapacityUnits" : "5", "WriteCapacityUnits" : "5" }
        }
    }
  },

  "Outputs" : {
    "UnderlyingDynamoTable" : {
        "Value" : { "Fn::If" : ["CreateDynamoTable", {"Ref":"DynamoTable"}, { "Ref" : "TableName" } ] }
    },
    "LambdaRole" : {
        "Value" : {"Fn::If" : ["CreateRole", {"Fn::GetAtt":["LambdaRole", "Arn"]}, {"Ref":"RoleARN"} ] }
    }
  }
}
```

I could just remove the creation step and create the resource manually before the API Gateway, but it seems like what I am trying to do should be possible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you are updating your existing stack, do not change the parameters. So even when you are updating your stack, set `ShouldCreateTable` to `true`.

Yes, it seems counter-intuitive when updating your stack to say "Create a table", when a table already exists, but you need to do that.

The reason is this:

1. When the stack is created, you set `ShouldCreateTable` to `true`, and the template applies it's conditional logic and creates the table as it's own managed resource.
2. When the stack is updated, you set `ShouldCreateTable` to `false`, and the template applies it's conditional logic and determines you no longer need the managed table because you're providing your own now. The resource should be deleted. It does not recognize that the table is the same.

When using your template, only say `ShouldCreateTable` == `false` if you are providing your own table **that you created**.

Comment: Is there a way to actually block the deletion? would the policy help?

Comment: @Efren please post this as a new SO question.

Comment: Hi @matt-houser, here it is: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50322859/cloudformation-block-deleting-resources

Answer (score 0):

Try to use Conditional statements and pass them as a Parameter to create the bucket or not

```
AWSTemplateFormatVersion: 2010-09-09
Parameters:
  EnvType:
    Description: Environment type.
    Default: test
    Type: String
    AllowedValues:
      - prod
      - test
    ConstraintDescription: must specify prod or test.
Conditions:
  CreateProdResources: !Equals 
    - !Ref EnvType
    - prod
Resources:
  EC2Instance:
    Type: 'AWS::EC2::Instance'
    Properties:
      ImageId: ami-0ff8a91507f77f867
  MountPoint:
    Type: 'AWS::EC2::VolumeAttachment'
    Condition: CreateProdResources
    Properties:
      InstanceId: !Ref EC2Instance
      VolumeId: !Ref NewVolume
      Device: /dev/sdh
  NewVolume:
    Type: 'AWS::EC2::Volume'
    Condition: CreateProdResources
    Properties:
      Size: 100
      AvailabilityZone: !GetAtt 
        - EC2Instance
        - AvailabilityZone
```

Follow the sample condition flow to decide wheather to create a resource or not.
[See this for more details](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/conditions-section-structure.html)