# CloudFormation: Block deleting resources

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation

A spinoff from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45147726/1736679). Trying to make a cloudformation template safe during changes.

Is there a way to actually block the deletion of the role and table? Would adding a policy help?

Given the following template excerpt:

```
{
  ...

  "Parameters" : {
    "ShouldCreateTable" : {
      ...
      "Description" : "If true then the underlying DynamoDB table will be created with the CloudFormation stack."
    },  
    ...
  },

  "Conditions" : {
    "CreateDynamoTable" : {"Fn::Equals" : [{"Ref" : "ShouldCreateTable"}, "true"]},
    ...
  },

  "Resources" : {

    "Get" : {
      "Type" : "AWS::Serverless::Function",
      "Properties": {
        ...
        "Role": {"Fn::If" : ["CreateRole", {"Fn::GetAtt":["LambdaRole", "Arn"]}, {"Ref":"RoleARN"}]},
        "Environment" : {
          "Variables" : {
            "AppDynamoTable" : { "Fn::If" : ["CreateDynamoTable", {"Ref":"DynamoTable"}, { "Ref" : "TableName" } ] }
          }
        },
        ...
      }
    },

    "LambdaRole":{
        "Type":"AWS::IAM::Role",
         ...
    },

    "DynamoTable" : {
        "Type" : "AWS::DynamoDB::Table",
        ...
    }
  },

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution could be to use [`DeletionPolicy Attribute`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-attribute-deletionpolicy.html). You can easily add `"DeletionPolicy" : "Retain"` to your resources where you want to "block" the deletion.

> AWS CloudFormation keeps the resource without deleting the resource or
>   its contents when its stack is deleted. You can add this deletion
>   policy to any resource type.

This would look in your given example like this:

```
"LambdaRole":{
  "Type":"AWS::IAM::Role",
  "DeletionPolicy" : "Retain",
  ...
},
"DynamoTable" : {
  "Type" : "AWS::DynamoDB::Table",
  "DeletionPolicy" : "Retain",
  ...
}
```