# AWS CloudFormation: create role only if role does not exist

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-sdk, aws-cloudformation

We use Jenkins to automate our EC deployments.

Subsequent deployments are failing after the first initial successful deployment because CF is complaining that the role we are attempting to create in our CF template already exists.

After discovering in the documentation that these updates are not possible if the Role resource is named, I tried removing the name, and received a permissions failure related to the Jenkins user attempting to create the role.

The Condition documentation doesn't clearly describe to me what the condition syntax should be to check if the role already exists.

I had half a thought to delete the role in a separate Jenkins step using the aws cli, but was scared away by the behavior of `iam delete-role` and existing instances (these should be non-interrupted updates).

How can I conditionally create a role resource, based on whether the role already exists?

The closest question I found was [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45147726/cloudformation-create-resources-if-they-do-not-exist-but-do-not-delete-them), but its related to DynamoDB.

Existing YAML for role creation (above and below the policy definitions are boilerplate):

```
Resources:
  MySESRole:
    Type: AWS::IAM::Role
    Properties:
      RoleName: MySESRole
      AssumeRolePolicyDocument:
        Version: '2012-10-17'
        Statement:
        - Action: "sts:AssumeRole"
          Principal:
            Service: ["ecs-tasks.amazonaws.com", "ecs.amazonaws.com"]
          Effect: "Allow"
      ManagedPolicyArns:
        - arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/AmazonSESFullAccess
```

Comment: Are you using the update stack? Or running the CFT as a new stack?

Comment: Its a new stack each time.

Comment: That does not work as the role names are unique. Did you try updating the existing stack.

Comment: I did, and get some unrelated error. Something up within our pipeline that I haven't taken the time to track down yet, but it looks like I am going to have to. Are you saying I can't use a Condition for Role resource creation like you can with other resources?

Comment: I have not seen such a capability. we never had any issues while updating the existing cloudformation stack.

Comment: this is interesting. thanks for the insight.